# Problems collecting 280 characters using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to extract tweets using the following code, and I just realized I'm only getting the first 140 characters. I'm a bit new at this and now I need to put tweet_mode=extended and full_text somewhere, so if someone could point out exactly where I'd be very appreciative. Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv

```
#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "5f55VEYRnHuBvVESy11OrBayI"
consumer_secret = "r0PcvNast4FLYD1HNQiJIsIDGtk72hhVFPzR3BfrIWfuSn2SWD"
access_key = "949748064985722880-Wpc3hErpGEeDC75MBfcDoo07X9WVcAo"
access_secret = "w02RdHMg1izgaFlKUJH3C5s9cDNue2h8XJv87E3TE0Whm"


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
#Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with 
this method

#authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []    

#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum 
allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 
screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv    
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-
8"),tweet.retweet_count,tweet.favorite_count] for tweet in alltweets]

#write the csv    
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

`writer.writerow(["id","created_at","full_text","retweet_count","favorite_count"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)`

```
pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
#pass in the username of the account you want to download
get_all_tweets("realdonaldtrump")
```

Answer (score 3):

Put "tweet_mode=extended" here:

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,
                               count=200,
                               tweet_mode=extended)
```

And here:

```
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,
                                   count=200,
                                   max_id=oldest,
                                   tweet_mode=extended)
```

Put "full_tweet" here:

```
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, 
              tweet.created_at, 
              tweet.full_tweet.encode("utf-8"),
              tweet.retweet_count,
              tweet.favorite_count] for tweet in alltweets]
```